# Ubuntu server installation sets invalid FQDN

Tags: networking, server

I recently installed the Raspberry Pi Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS (64-bit) image, with their imager tool:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

# hostnamectl
 Static hostname: apollo
       Icon name: computer
      Machine ID: f1d5fae30ffc434680ebcb59c2f5a582
         Boot ID: af1da6b8a7384f5fa5b35896935dfbf6
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-1044-raspi
    Architecture: arm64

# resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (eth0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.4.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.4.1
        DNS Domain: lan

# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan
```

I have a strange behaviour related the FQDN in Ubuntu, which I never experienced before with Debian:

```
# hostname --short
apollo
# hostname --fqdn
apollo
# hostname --all-fqdns
apollo.lan
# cat /etc/hosts | grep 127.0.1.1
127.0.1.1 apollo apollo
```

As you can see above, during the installation, the FQDN is wrongly set, the `--all-fqdns` reverse DNS lookup returns the correct value because is looking into `192.168.4.1` also. For now, I manually edited `/etc/hosts`:

```
# cat /etc/hosts | grep 127.0.1.1
127.0.1.1 apollo.lan apollo
```

I'm trying to determine what is the proper fix for this issue, thank you for your help.